# Qt Video Player generates a blank screen?

Tags: c++, qt, video

I haven't found any related issues to my problem so I figure I must be missing something simple. 
I placed this small chunk of code in a function to create a basic video player.

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;

player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/sample_iTunes.mov"));
QVideoWidget* videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

videoWidget->show();
player->play();
```

A blank screen will open up, which is the videoWidget, and neither video nor sound will play. There aren't many lines of code so I figure there is either an error or I'm missing something. I toyed around with many different files (.mp4, .mov, .mp3) and those didn't work, as well as not using a local file and linking to a random youtube video (didn't work either). Any suggestions?

Comment: Well. I tried your code, but of course with a different video file, and it worked fine. I use Windows 8, VS2013, Qt 5.4.1. So I don't know how to help :(.

Comment: Well that's interesting. Do you think my local path is incorrect? I checked it doing a simple checker using .exists() && .isFile() on the path, and it returned true, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe that a good idea. When I try something like this I always move the file first to for example D:/example.mov which is easier to check :).

Comment: Well it doesn't work, still. What kind of video file did you use? Do you mind sharing the file path that you put into the Qurl?

Comment: It was this simple: `player->setMedia( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "C:/1.mov" ) );`. One of my old video files. I changed only file path, nothing else from your code.

Comment: Guess I'm at a loss then. I'll have to wait till tomorrow when I can talk to some coworkers about it (I'm interning). Thank you! :)

Comment: If you just try to view the file with a standard video player does it work ?

Comment: Yeah it does. I've also tried the sample video Wildlife.wmv which doesn't work either (but viewable).

Comment: Very. Could it be some codec issue? Not very experienced with any of this lingo, but google has led me to some of these terms.

Comment: If your code compiles, and the codecs are good then I think it shall work. It works on my PC.

Comment: Super weird. This isn't my computer (working in an office) so I don't know anything about codecs and if this computer has them or not.

Comment: Which Windows version are you on?

Comment: That computer is using Windows 7. I was told to use error from QtMediaPlayer, I'm still new at using Qt in general so I'll have to figure that out. Any suggestions really helps though.

Comment: So I implemented some error debugging and I got this response:5, The QMediaPlayer object does not have a valid service. I installed the k-lite codec basic package but this hasn't fixed anything either. How do I go about this from here?